# How to multiply two hex numbers in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell script

I Have tried to multiply two hex numbers in shell script in the following manner.

```
initial= expr 0x10000 \* 0x22
echo $initial
```

While running the script,The following error is seen.

```
expr: non-numeric argument
```

Can someone point out what might the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to `expr`, use `$(( ))` just like this:

```
$ echo $((0x10000 * 0x22))
2228224
```

Or you can use `bc` like this, indicating input is hex (`ibase`) and desired output also in hex (`obase`) (as [Adobe's deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24671788/1983854) states):

```
$ echo "ibase=16; obase=16; 10000*22" | bc
 09 11 05 16 20

$ echo "ibase=16; 10000*22" | bc
2228224
```

Comment: This isn't portable to legacy Bourne shell, though.